# Open PDF from server in browser with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, browser

Hi I would like to open a PDF file from a server in my browser with javascript.

So I have a PDF file stored on a server for example this url: `file://myServer/folder1/myFile.pdf`

The web-space of my web-application is local on my client, so I can't use relative path to open the PDF file in the browser (`Google Chrome`, `Safari` and `Internet Explorer`). So there is a json like this:

```
let files = {
    url: 'file://myServer/folder1/myFile.pdf'
}
```

I tried it with `window.open(files.url);`, but it only workes on `Internet Explorer`, on the other browsers it's a `about:blank` empty page. I also read, that this isn't really the best way to do this. How can I get the PDF file from the server and open it in a new tab on one of this browsers? Any ideas?

Thanks.